# PHP change value of array by reference

Tags: php

Here's sample code:

```
<?php

$arr1 = [ 'foo' => 'bar', 'test' => '2' ];
$arr2 = [ 'foo' => 'bar', 'test' => '2' ];

$arr3 = [ $arr1, $arr2 ];

$randomArr = $arr3[mt_rand(0, count($arr3) -1)];

$randomArr['test'] = 3;

echo "$arr1: " . print_r($arr1, true);
echo "$arr2: " . print_r($arr2, true);
```

What I'm trying to do here is change the value of `$arr1['test']` or `$arr2['test']`, at random, to `3`. It seems `$randomArr` gets copied by value and not by reference. Is there a way to do a copy by reference so that I can change `$arr1` or `$arr2` inline?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 6):

You can create an array of references to your other arrays.

```
$arr3 = [ &$arr1, &$arr2 ];
```

Then update one of the arrays directly without creating `$randomArr`.

```
$arr3[mt_rand(0, count($arr3) -1)]['test'] = 3;
```

Comment: What if multiple keys need to have their values updated for the same array?

Comment: In that case you could create `$randomArr` as before, but assign it by reference as well. Pretty much like the other answer that @gview added just as I replied to your comment :)

Answer (score 4):

Or you can using your code do this as well:

```
<?php

$arr1 = [ 'foo' => 'bar', 'test' => '2' ];
$arr2 = [ 'foo' => 'bar', 'test' => '2' ];

$arr3 = [ &$arr1, &$arr2 ];

$randomArr = &$arr3[mt_rand(0, count($arr3) -1)];

print_r($randomArr);
$randomArr['test'] = 3;

echo "$arr1: " . print_r($arr1, true);
echo "$arr2: " . print_r($arr2, true);
```